# Dual boot CentOS Live OS

Tags: linux, dual-boot, grub

I want to put CentOS Live OS in one of my HDD partitions and when system boots I want the booting screen to show two kernels:

1. the normal one
2. the Live OS

Is it possible to make a partition and put the live OS in that partition?

How should Grub be changed?

Comment: I have centos installed in my HDD now I have been told to make a new partition and put live os centos in that only partition might be of 6 Gb than I need to have 2 booting options first one the main one already installed one and second live os ,

Comment: Use the "edit" link to improve/clarify your question. The better the question will be, the more upvotes it will get, and the more people will be willing to reading it to start with and answer it if they can. Please also delete your own answer which is not a real answer.

Comment: HI,

I have made a script abc.sh, now i want it to display its version when i run it.
suppose im running script, ./abc.sh -v, i want it to display its version number.
plz answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution to this would be:

Step 1: Create a partition from CentOS on the HDD; **Caution** *[It should be a separate/blank disk because restoration will wipe it completely, created un-allocated space for free space]*
Step 2: Use the ISO/live CD and use "Restore Disk Image" option to clone the Live OS contents to the new partition;
Step 3: Add an new menuentry of the kernel from the Live OS partition to the existing grub and build it.

Comment: HI,

I have made a script abc.sh, now i want it to display its version when i run it.
suppose im running script, ./abc.sh -v, i want it to display its version number.
,plz answer this